# How can i add marker tomtom in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tomtom

I want to add a marker in tomtom. I would like to define a map in "data" but when I do this it gives me an error:

```
maps.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property '__om' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value (expected '#<i>' but got '#<i>')
```

The error shows up only after I add "new tt.Marker". If I define a map directly in this method it works (instead of this.map I will use the map variable).

This is my vue code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="map" id="map" ref="mapRef"></div>
</template>

<script>
import tt from '@tomtom-international/web-sdk-maps';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      map: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initializeMap()
  },
  methods: {
    initializeMap() {
    this.map = tt.map({
    key: 'key',
    container: this.$refs.mapRef,
    center: [-120.72217631449985, 42.73919549715691],
    zoom: 10
  });


  //Here I get error
  new tt.Marker()
      .setLngLat([-120.72217631449985, 42.73919549715691])
      .addTo(this.map);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` properties are made reactive by default, which appears to conflict with the operation of Tomtom Maps API. However, reactivity is not actually needed in this case.

The `map` property should be set to a frozen object with [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to workaround the issue:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    initializeMap() {
      const map = tt.map(/*...*/);
      new tt.Marker().setLngLat(/*...*/).addTo(map);
                           
      this.map = Object.freeze(map);
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-tomtom?file=src/App.vue)